# Filter users on StackOverflow not working on Google Chrome

Tags: bug, status-norepro, javascript

I've noticed today that the [Users](https://stackoverflow.com/users) page on StackOverflow is throwing a javascript error when loaded in Google Chrome (4.0.249.78 36714 Windows 7 x64). Here's the message:

```
jquery.typewatch.js:89 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token =
users:23 Uncaught TypeError: Object #<an Object> has no method 'typeWatch'
```

This prevents from filtering the list.

Comment: Same here. Oddly enough it works fine on MSO.

Comment: Works for me. What version are you using?

Comment: Works for me too on Chrome 4.0.249.78 (36714).

Comment: 4.0.249.78 36714 Windows 7 x64

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can't reproduce this on Chrome 4.0.249.78 -- have you tried clearing your cache?

Comment: @Jeff, you were correct. It seems that this is caused by this Flash Block extension I've installed (https://chrome.google.com/extensions/detail/gofhjkjmkpinhpoiabjplobcaignabnl). Disabling it solves the problem.